# Change configuration folder structure in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, sails.js

I just want to have another folder structure in sails.js. For example, something like:

```
/config
    /application
        routes.js
        policies.js
    /db
        connections.js
...
```

It seems like when lifting application sails look for each of that files (`console.log` to `/config/application/policies.js` works when application getting lifted) anyway it does not work.

I try to add `paths.config` value to `.sailsrc` but it changes nothing. I an using sails version 0.10.5 now. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Actually, everything is very simple.

sails requires files from `config` folder recursively and tries to recognize them as configuration files. My problem was that I had copied most files as is:

```
// config/customfolder/connections.js
module.exports.connections = {
    ...
}
```

and here is the problem to require it. To make it work I just need to export config object as default export.

```
// config/customfolder/connections.js
module.exports = {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Odd, I was having this problem because I was using `module.exports` and once I named the module to something like `module.exports.blah = function()...` it worked fine.